# IOC Container locking during integration tests

Tags: c#, integration-testing, simple-injector

When doing a check in, I run integration tests, but every once in a while it seems that my container is locking up.

1. It happens on different integration tests
2. It doesn't always happen

The error is :

> The container can't be changed after the first call to GetInstance,
>   GetAllInstances, Verify, and some calls of GetRegistration. Please see
>   https://simpleinjector.org/locked to understand why the container is
>   locked.

The one it locked on just now is this implementation:

```
 public SnsTests()
        {
            var container = new Container();
            IocBootstrapper.RegisterComponents(container);
            _container = IocBootstrapper.GetConfiguredContainer();
        }
```

Each one of my test classes registers an IOC container like above (I think that might be a large part of my problem)... However, how do I fix it?

Bootstrapper class:

```
public static class IocBootstrapper
    {
        private static Container _container = new Container();
        public static void RegisterComponents(Container container)
        {
            _container = container;
            IocConfig.RegisterTypes(container);
        }

        public static Container GetConfiguredContainer()
        {
            return _container;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a container in your tests at all?

Comment: Sound like tests are using a shared resource that is leading to race conditions.

Comment: @Nkosi I also suspect a race condition, just not sure what it would be...  I've updated the post.

Comment: @RandomUs1r you would need to do a review of your design. It is way too broad to identify what could be the shared resource being used from what is shown. I was initially looking at the `IocBootstrapper`

Comment: @Nkosi I suspect it's firing off RegisterComponents as a GetInstance is happening... but in a different class.  Anyways I added my bootstrapper class to alleviate the mystery.  Let me know if I'm missing anything major.

Comment: @RandomUs1r yep it is the **static** bootstrapper that multiple tests will potentially be updating at the same time. One test could grab the container just before trying to register components

Comment: Your question misses some vital information, which is the second part of the exception message. The .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 versions of Simple Injector add the stack trace to the exception message that shown what code path caused the container to lock. Either you are using the .NET Standard 1.3 version of Simple Injector (which does not include this information), using a really old version, or you didn't add the completed exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Although state integration tests, it appears tests are using a shared resource that is leading to race conditions.

Tests, whether unit or integration, should should be isolated from each other to avoid such situations.

Suggest performing what happens in the bootstrapper individually in the tests

```
public SnsTests() {
    var container = new Container();
    IocConfig.RegisterTypes(container);
    _container = container;
}
```